# character count not working right for validate.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Wonder if this is doable. I am setting a validator for a form like this

```
function addFormRules(selector,rules) {
        $form.find(selector).each(function() {
            $(this).rules('add', rules);
        });
    }
```

and add the rules like this. The $form is a global variable which returns a form

```
addFormRules('textarea[id*="contactus_comment"]' , {
        required: false,
        rangelength: [2, 5000],
        messages: {
            //required: msg.VALIDATE_CONTACTUSMINLENGTH,
            rangelength: function(range, input) {
                return [
                    range[1] - $(input).val().length,
                    ' characters remaining'                                
                ].join('');

            }

        }
    });
```

The intention is to show how many characters left before I hit the max limit. Which seems to stop working right after I pass the range[0]...And it also doesnt let me submit my form until the character count doesnt reach the max limit. The form should not be blocked from being submitted if it doesnt reach the max character range. If it exceeds yes then I understand

Comment: *"Wonder if this is doable"* ~ did you try it?

Comment: @Sparky -- yeah I did try it. And it doesn't work :-(..it gives me the character  remaining till it hits range[0]..after that it disapears

Comment: The `rangelength: [2, 5000]` rule says that your input will trigger a validation error if you type less than 2 or more than 5000 characters. So your `rangelength` message function is not going to do anything unless you have a validation error.

Comment: I think you need to show us enough code to construct a working demo of this issue.

Comment: @Sparky -- yeah. So basically cant use rangelength attribute for this. I wish I could though

Comment: Cool...will add a link from my repo shortly..need to decouple stuff from the actual app to make it a standalone problem

Comment: IMO, it's a bad idea to couple your character counter into form validation... they're really two different things.

Comment: this what I ended up doing really....easy enough and works well...
https://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/j2dj0uvf/3/

I am glad we got to have the discussion and I ended up changing my approach ...thanks!

Comment: Since your solution has nothing to do with jQuery Validate, I assume you no longer seek an answer here.  In that case, please consider deleting this question.  Otherwise, please post the code from your solution into an answer below and explain.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sparky -- I think the question can stay. There are plenty of dummies like me and they deserve to know what can and can not be done with the plugin. Documentations are great but questions and findings have their own space. I think I will keep the question up. But thanks for the suggestion though. :-). I do appreciate that

Comment: I think you missed the last part of my last comment:  *"**Otherwise**, please post the code from your solution into an answer below and explain. Thanks."*